# How to increase the Player class Size Upon collision?

Tags: python, class, pygame, size

I am currently working on a square collecting game in which the User/Player will be a blue square that can only collect squares that are smaller than the player's square. These are represented by color, if the square is smaller than the player than it is green, if it is bigger it will be red.

I have run into a problem where I can not figure out how to INCREASE THE SIZE of the Player when the player collides with the green squares. I have tried a number of different things that don't seem to work and would appreciate some different options to try and accomplish this task.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the ball.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ The class is the player-controlled sprite. """

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        # -- Attributes
        # Set speed vector
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        """ Change the speed of the player"""
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        """ Find a new position for the player"""
        # move left or right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.x = 1
            wall_sound.play()
        if self.rect.x >= 680:
            self.rect.x = 679
            wall_sound.play()
        # move up or down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        if self.rect.y <= 0:
            self.rect.y = 1
            wall_sound.play()
        if self.rect.y >= 385:
            self.rect.y = 384
            wall_sound.play()


# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'Group.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# This is a list of every sprite. 
# All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create a BLUE player block
p_width = 30
p_height = 25
p_size = (p_width, p_height)
player = Player(p_width, p_height)
all_sprites_list.add(player)

# BLOCK LIST 
for i in range(50):
    width = random.randrange(20, 50)
    height = width - 5
    b_size = (width, height)
    if b_size <= p_size:
        color = GREEN
    if b_size > p_size:
        color = RED
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(color, width, height)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width - width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height - height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Pygame sound effects

collect_good = pygame.mixer.Sound("SnowWalk.ogg")
collect_bad = pygame.mixer.Sound("icebreaks.ogg")
wall_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("evillaugh.ogg")

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

score = 0

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

     # Set the speed based on the key pressed
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        # Reset speed when key goes up
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            eli
    # See if the player block has collided with anything.
        #good
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    # Check the list of collisions.
        #good
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score += 1
        collect_good.play()

    if score <= -1:
        done = True
    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(text, [20, 300])

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()f event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

     # This calls update on all the sprites
    all_sprites_list.update()

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # See if the player block has collided with anything.
        #good
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    # Check the list of collisions.
        #good
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score += 1
        collect_good.play()

    if score <= -1:
        done = True
    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(text, [20, 300])

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Why can't you just add to height and width?

Comment: @Natecat I do have the height and width (p_width and p_height) of the player but i need a condition when the player block collides with a green block that the p_height and p_width increase.

Answer (score 0):

Make the player constructor take the width and height as well as the x and y.  In the collision check, increase these and create a new image for the player with the new increased x and y values.  Don't forget to reset the player rect at the same time as well.

Also, you are passing the width and height in and using them as x and y not width and height.